# Zero trick for normal density in JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

In page 200-202 of the book "Beginner's Guide to GLM and GLMM" by Alain F. Zuur et al., the zero trick method was introduced, which served as a powerful way of fitting any distribution in JAGS. This technique requires taking logarithm of the density function. For normal density, it logarithm form appears as follows in the book:
[image]

The JAGS code is as below:

```
cat("
model{
#1A. Diffuse normal priors for the regression
# coefficients
for (i in 1:K) { beta[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001) }
#1B. half-Cauchy(25) prior for the variance
num ~ dnorm(0, 0.0016)
denom ~ dnorm(0, 1)
sigma <- abs(num / denom)
#2. Likelihood
C <- 10000
for (i in 1:N){
Zeros[i] ~ dpois(Zeros.mean[i])
Zeros.mean[i] <- -L[i] + C
l1[i] <- -0.5 * log(2 * 3.1415) –
0.5 * log(sigma)
l2[i] <- -0.5 * pow(Biomass[i]-mu[i],2)/sigma
L[i] <- l1[i] + l2[i]
mu[i] <- eta[i]
eta[i] <- inprod(beta[],X[i,])
}
}
",fill = TRUE)
```

The author explicitly model `sigma` as following half-Cauchy(25) distribution, thus it is clear that the `sigma` in the code represents standard deviation not variance. This suggests that `sigma^2` should be used in the code as indicated by the formula for log density. However, the object l1[i] uses `0.5 * log(sigma)` instead of `0.5 * log(sigma^2)`, similarly, l2[i] includes `sigma` instead of `sigma^2` in the denominator.

I wish to know why the formula and the corresponding code seem to treat `sigma` differently.

Comment: FYI, the zero trick method is explained in Chapter 8 of "Ntzoufras I (2009) Bayesian Modeling Using WinBUGS. Wiley: Hoboken NJ"

Comment: *"thus it is clear that the sigma in the code represents standard deviation not variance"* I don't think that is correct; everything points towards `sigma` being in fact the variance and not the standard deviation. The half-Cauchy density as the ratio of two independent normals is a prior on the *variance* (`sigma` in the code above); the log-likelihood is also consistent with `sigma` referring to the *variance* and not the standard deviation.

Comment: The paper "Non-Standard Semiparametric Regression via BRugs"  by Marley and Wand (2010) indicated that half-Cauchy distribution from the ratio of two normal variables is the prior for standard deviation. Using half-Cauchy distribution as the prior for variance seems not evidenced by the literature.

Comment: *"Using half-Cauchy distribution as the prior for variance seems not evidenced by the literature"* I don't think that is necessarily correct; from a statistical point of view it does not matter whether you define a weakly informative prior on the sd or variance. All I'm saying is that based on the code *you* give, `sigma` seems to indicate the sd rather than the variance. This might be unconventional but I don't see the problem. Whether the normal is parametrised in terms of `sigma` or `sigma^2` is quite arbitrary.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I totally understand and agree with your statement. Perhaps it is unusal, but there is no absolute right or wrong. Thank you.

Comment: No worries @Patrick; good luck with your work.